# Join DataFrame based on date which is between dates from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas Data Frames. First one looks like (`db1`):

```
id   date_from   date_until   v1   v2
0    2015-06-17  2015-06-19    2    3
0    2015-06-17  2015-07-01    3    4 
1    2015-06-18  2015-06-20    5    6
1    2015-06-19  2015-07-12    5    4
```

and the second one (`db2`), like this:

```
id      date      v3   v4
0    2015-06-17   4    3
1    2015-06-17   5    6 
1    2015-06-18   6    4
```

no i want to compress them so they based on `id` and `date`. Date compression should be if `db2.date` is older or equal than `db1.date_from` and use the youngest one from `db2` witch is still older or equal than `db1.data_from`. 
So compressed data should look something like this:

```
id   date_from   date_until      date      v1   v2   v3   v4
0    2015-06-17  2015-06-19   2015-06-17   2    3    4    3
0    2015-06-17  2015-07-01   2015-06-17   3    4    4    3
1    2015-06-18  2015-06-20   2015-06-18   5    6    6    4
1    2015-06-19  2015-07-12   2015-06-18   5    4    6    4
```

I can't find any solution except iterating trough all rows, but this is not good enough because my data is bigger 100k of lines. Is there any tool to do this in pandas or should i use something else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use [`pd.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas-merge-asof):

```
pd.merge_asof(df1,df2, left_on=['date_from'], right_on=['date'], by='id')
```

Output:

```
   id  date_from  date_until  v1  v2       date  v3  v4
0   0 2015-06-17  2015-06-19   2   3 2015-06-17   4   3
1   0 2015-06-17  2015-07-01   3   4 2015-06-17   4   3
2   1 2015-06-18  2015-06-20   5   6 2015-06-18   6   4
3   1 2015-06-19  2015-07-12   5   4 2015-06-18   6   4
```

Comment: Almost as if the question was tailor made for merge_asof :-)

Comment: hah!  I hadn't thought of that. Just nice to see merge_asof get some attention

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

a = StringIO('''id,date_from,date_until,v1,v2
0,2015-06-17,2015-06-19,2,3
0,2015-06-17,2015-07-01,3,4
1,2015-06-18,2015-06-20,5,6
1,2015-06-19,2015-07-12,5,4''')

b = StringIO('''id,date,v3,v4
0,2015-06-17,4,3
1,2015-06-17,5,6 
1,2015-06-18,6,4''')

df1 = pd.read_csv(a, sep=',')
df2 = pd.read_csv(b, sep=',')
df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['id', 'date_from'], right_on=['id', 'date']).ffill()
```