# Pandas: Map rows from one dataframe to another based on a time condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, each containing different kinds of events on a server.

For each event (row) in dataframe A, I want to look through dataframe B and find events that happen within a certain window of time before, and copy their ID (a value in one of its columns) to a new column in the current row of A.

There's an arbitrary number of rows from dataframe B that can map to a row from dataframe A, and rows from B can be mapped to multiple rows in A.

So far this is what I have, but I get "TypeError: len() of unsized object" when using A.set_value(...)

```
    time_frame = datetime.timedelta(hours=48)
    for index, row in A.iterrows():
        window = [pd.to_datetime(row['Time']),
                   pd.to_datetime(row['Time']) - datetime.timedelta(hours=time_frame)]
        mask = (B['Time'] < window[0]) & (B['Time'] > window[1])
        temp = B.loc(mask)
        A.set_value(index, 'related event', temp['ID'])
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a simple test case:

```
dA = {'ID' : ['A1923', 'A1922', 'A1921', 'A1920'], 'Time' : ['2017-01-23 19:16:01',
 '2017-01-22 10:52:30', '2017-01-15  16:34:22', '2017-01-05 08:31:28']}

dB = {'ID' : ['B8392', 'B8391', 'B8390', 'B8389', 'B8388', 'B8387'], 'Time' : 
['2017-01-23 11:23:55', '2017-01-22 22:47:31', '2017-01-22 09:19:07', 
'2017-01-19 01:22:18', '2017-01-15 04:38:11', '2017-01-14 18:18:51']}

A = pd.DataFrame(dA)
B = pd.DataFrame(dB)

find_relations(A, B)
```

Ideally, the output would be:

```
     ID             Time          Related
0  A1923   2017-01-23 19:16:01   B8392, B8391, B8390   
1  A1922   2017-01-22 10:52:30   B8390
2  A1921   2017-01-15 16:34:22   B8388, B8387
3  A1920   2017-01-05 08:31:28   NaN
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of each input dataframe and expected output?

Comment: I edited an example.

Comment: Look at `pd.merge_asof' and see this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43849865/join-dataframe-based-od-date-witch-is-between-dates-from-another-dataframe/43850080#43850080) as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution, the problem had to do with the creation of the 'related' column as well as the timedelta object not being copmpatible, and the way I was creating the temporary dataframe to store all the related rows from B.

```
def find_relations(A, B, time_window=48):
    A['related'] = ""
    for index, row in A.iterrows():
        window = [pd.to_datetime(row['Time']),
              pd.to_datetime(row['Time']) - DateOffset(hours=time_window)]
        mask = (pd.to_datetime(B['Time']) < window[0]) & (pd.to_datetime(B['Time']) > window[1])
        temp = B[mask]
        A.set_value(index, 'related', ','.join(list(temp['ID'])))
```

So, first we have to make the empty column in the A dataframe by assigning it to the empty string object. Then, instead of the timedelta, it works better to use a DateOffset object from pandas.tseries.offsets to create the timewindow. Finally, the B.loc(mask) was not syntactically valid, so it was replaced it with B[mask].

The output is:

```
     ID                  Time       related
0  A1923   2017-01-23 19:16:01  B8392,B8391,B8390
1  A1922   2017-01-22 10:52:30              B8391
2  A1921   2017-01-15 16:34:22        B8388,B8387
3  A1920   2017-01-05 08:31:28
```